# Properly cascading this @OneToMany relationship (Spring Data JPA)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, cascade, many-to-one

Alright, I'm a little deperate right now. I've read many of the other related questions but this hasn't helped me resolve my issue yet. I'll be glad if someone can help me out.

I'm using Spring Data JPA and I have these two entities:

---

**Device.class**

```
private String id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "device", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnore
@RestResource(exported = false)
private List<Reading> readings;
```

**Reading.class**

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}) /*This isn't right...*/
@JoinColumn(name = "device_id")
private Device device;
```

---

**Expectation**

I'm only saving **Readings** and expect the **Device** to be cascaded correctly (persisted or merged), depending on whether it already exists. (Readings are only inserted once, they are never updated)

**Reality**

I can only make this work *partially*:

When I use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` or `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` I can save the *first* Reading and its mapped Device. Once I insert a second Reading that has a relationship to the same Device, I get something along the lines of:

```
Duplicate entry '457129' for key 'PRIMARY'
('457129' = Reading.Device.id)
```

As I understand, the second Reading entity tries to cascade its Device by inserting a new row instead of updating the existing one.

I can "work around" this by using `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE` instead. Now the device is updated correctly when I save a new Reading with an existing Device entity. **BUT** now I can no longer cascade a Device that doesn't yet exist!

```
Column 'device_id' cannot be null 
(Reading.device_id)
```

**The Save**

I receive JSON DTO's and create the entities from it.

Pseudocode:

```
Reading reading = deserialize(jsonReading);
Device device = deserialize(device);

reading.setDevice(device); /* Device entity is detached */

readingService.save(reading);
```

I guess part of the problem might have to do with me setting a detached entity?

What am I doing wrong? Are my realtionships bad? What is happening? Do I need to manage these transactions manually?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> The @OneToMany association is by definition a parent association, even if it’s a unidirectional or a bidirectional one. Only the parent side of an association makes sense to cascade its entity state transitions to children. (source: [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-one)).

Based on the documentation I will remove the `cascade` from the `device` field. Docs also contains code examples for storing `Phone` and `Person` for `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` that you may try.

As you didn't post any code for saving part I suppose that you set device before saving the `reading` as

```
reading.setDevice(device);
readingDao.save(reading); // depends on your implementation
```

When persisting `reading` object the `device` should be saved automatically.

Comment: I removed the ``cascade`` but that didn't help. Still getting ``Column 'device_id' cannot be null ``. I also added the saving part to the question since it might be important.

Comment: Do you have primary keys defined with `@Id` annotation? Also, if you are creating new objects leave the id values and use them when updating (but call `saveOrUpdate` in the Dao implementation instead of `save`)

Comment: Yes. ``@Id @GeneratedValue private int id;`` on ``Reading``. ``@Id private String id;`` on ``Device``.

Comment: Try to change device id field to be the same as in reading. Duplicated entry indicates that you are trying to insert a device that alredy exists. If you need one device to be used in more readings you should use ManyToMany relation.